# Empty gallery echo message displays 3x regardless of true/false rule

Tags: php, html

Ok, I'm pretty new to php and my question might be incredibly foolish but I've tried every combination I could think of and cannot get this to work properly.

Either it doesn't display a message in the empty gallery at all or it displays it three times in every gallery regardless of it containing images.

I know that the thumbnail perimeters are not the most desirable ones but I've tried to work in an auto image crop perimeter to create the thumbnails and could not get it to work for the life of me.

My main concern is now the empty gallery message, but if you can help me with incorporating a reliable image crop snippet to create better thumbnails.. please do :)

```
function lightbox_display($dir_to_search, $rel){
    $image_dir = $dir_to_search;
    $dir_to_search = scandir($dir_to_search);
    $image_exts = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
    $excluded_filename = '_t';
    foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
        $dot = strrpos($image_file, '.');
        $filename = substr($image_file, 0, $dot);
        $filetype = substr($image_file, $dot+1);
        $thumbnail_file = strrpos($filename, $excluded_filename);
        if ((!$thumbnail_file) and array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false){
            echo "<a href='".$image_dir.$image_file."' rel='".$rel."'>
                  <img src='".$image_dir.$image_file."' alt='".$filename."' width='100' height='80' title='' border='none'/>
                  </a>"."\n";
        } else {
            echo 'Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.';
        }
    }
}
```

Updated php coding:

I tried adding an array to the $imagesFound to rule out the possible inclusion of the folders server side.

```
    function lightbox_display($dir_to_search, $rel){
    $image_dir = $dir_to_search;
    $dir_to_search = scandir($dir_to_search);
    $image_exts = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
    $excluded_filename = '_t';
    $imagesFound = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png') && 0;
        foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
        $dot = strrpos($image_file, '.');
        $filename = substr($image_file, 0, $dot);
        $filetype = substr($image_file, $dot+1);
        $thumbnail_file = strrpos($filename, $excluded_filename);
    if ((!$thumbnail_file) && array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false) {
    $imagesFound++;
    echo "<a href='$image_dir$image_file' rel='$rel'>
          <img src='$image_dir$image_file' alt='$filename' width='100' height='80' title='' border='none'/>
          </a>\n";
}

    if ((0 === $imagesFound) !== true){
    echo 'Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.';
}
   }
 }
```

Comment: `if ((!$thumbnail_file) and ...`  the AND does not exist in PHP. What you search for is `&&`. Maybe this already solves your problem?

Comment: When using double quotes you don't need to close them to concatenate variables, just use `"<a href='$image_dir$image_file' rel='…"`. BTW, how many elements does `$dir_to_search` contain?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have made the correction, I am still having the same problem with it displaying the echoed message in trifold on every page regardless of there being images in the designated folder.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, I had assumed that with it being coded in php I would have to use both, I removed the single quotes. (echo message problem still exists however)

Comment: I'm sorry Marcel, just now saw your question related to the elements; this is a stand alone php script which is being called upon in the various galleries where the $dir-to-search is set according to the gallery in question. The largest gallery contains 197 images.

Answer (score 1):

If it's displaying the same message three times, I assume there are three files in the `$dir_to_search` but none are images. They might be `.`, `..` and something else. You're outputting the message every time you find a file that isn't a valid image, it seems, so what you could do instead is the keep a count of how many images you've found, and only put out the text if you found none.  e.g.

```
$imagesFound = 0;
foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
    $dot = strrpos($image_file, '.');
    $filename = substr($image_file, 0, $dot);
    $filetype = substr($image_file, $dot+1);
    $thumbnail_file = strrpos($filename, $excluded_filename);
    if ((!$thumbnail_file) and array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false) {
        $imagesFound++;
        echo "<a href='$image_dir$image_file' rel='$rel'>
              <img src='$image_dir$image_file' alt='$filename' width='100' height='80' title='' border='none'/>
              </a>\n";
    }
}

if (0 === $imagesFound) {
    echo 'Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.';
}
```

Update in response to comments below:

If you are calling lightbox_display() more than once, and still only want the message to display once, you can return the number of images found and use that.  Something like this:

```
function lightbox_display($dir_to_search, $rel) {
    $imagesFound = 0;
    foreach ($dir_to_search as $image_file){
        if ((!$thumbnail_file) and array_search($filetype, $image_exts) !== false) {
            $imagesFound++;
            echo "<img...";
        }
    }
    return $imagesFound;
}

$totalImagesFound = 0;
foreach ($galleries as $gallery) {
    $totalImagesFound += lightbox_display($gallery['dir'], $rel);
}

if (0 === $totalImagesFound ) {
    echo 'Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.';
}
```

Maybe that will help, although without knowing more about your system, I don't really know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Daren; what you put together makes sense and I've added it to the code. However I have no message output on the empty gallery. I'm overlooking something, maybe an additional parameter that I need to set.

Comment: If you don't have anything set up for interactive debugging, I find that liberal use of `echo` and `var_dump` statements can help with diagnosing problems. Try just echoing out some stuff to help with checking that various bits of the code are being executed, and what values are being processed. e.g. `var_dump($image_file)`, `thumbnail_file` etc. Also make sure you *view source* because you might be writing out image/anchor tags with invalid image names. Maybe it should be `$image_dir/$image_file` if your dir doesn't have a slash at the end already.

Comment: Yes, the directory in the various galleries is called upon as such: lightbox_display('gallery-available/'). I will take your advice and play around with the echo and var_dump statements to see if I can figure it out. Thank you very much for your help so far, highly appreciated.

Comment: The message displays now, in trifold and in all galleries. The var_dump run on $image_file comes up with the following string: Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.string(1) "." Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.string(2) ".." Currently there are no machines available for sale, please check back with us soon.string(9) ".DS_Store" so you were correct in your assumption about the folders in the gallery folders; the $imagesFound didn't solve that either @DarenChandisingh

Comment: I'm not sure if you've implemented it differently, or the call to `lightbox_display()` is itself called more than once. I've updated the answer with another suggestion for the latter case.

Comment: Sorry for the bit late response; had a replacement machine for a few days which didn't allow me to do much of anything with the site. No, each gallery has their own folder and each have a different page with a different path to the directory called only once. If your statement would have been the case the gallery would display each photo in trifold as well. Your first observation concerning the dir's was correct however. I have a question, should $ImagesFound or $totalImagesFound not be assigned a property, to define the search parameters? The site is: dirtyirons.com @DarenChandisingh

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "be assigned a property", sorry. Can you update your question to show what the code currently looks like?

Comment: Updated, also tried the $imagesFound = array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png') && 0; as $imagesFound = 0 and array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');, to give it the "and" option with less precedence to add more flexibility to the parameters. But even though the message is not displayed in trifold anymore, it is not showing at all. @DarenChandisingh

Comment: Your problem is with `if ((0 === $imagesFound) !== true)`. You want the message to be displayed if `$imagesFound` is `0`, but your code is putting out the message if it's `false`; when no images had been found, `0 === $imagesFound` evaluates to `true`, but then you're checking that is `!== true` (i.e. is false). Just leave it as `if (0 === $imagesFound)`, as I originally showed it, and that should fix things.